# Consistent numeric type check

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, types, numbers

Let's leave the ducks in the pond.

Just to make it clear, I'm working with Python 2.7.3.

I was playing with number checks and came across a few things that I found odd:

```python
In [1]: numbers.Number.mro()
Out[1]: [numbers.Number, object]

In [2]: numbers.Complex.mro()
Out[2]: [numbers.Complex, numbers.Number, object]

In [3]: numbers.Real.mro()
Out[3]: [numbers.Real, numbers.Complex, numbers.Number, object]

In [4]: numbers.Rational.mro()
Out[4]: [numbers.Rational, numbers.Real, numbers.Complex,
         numbers.Number, object]

In [5]: numbers.Integral.mro()
Out[5]: [numbers.Integral, numbers.Rational, numbers.Real,
         numbers.Complex, numbers.Number, object]
```

This strikes me as... counter-productive and is somewhat contradictory within Python itself (`int`, `float`, `complex` just inherit from `object` directly):

```python
In [6]: isinstance(int(), complex)
Out[6]: False

In [7]: isinstance(int(), numbers.Complex)
Out[7]: True
```

Then I wrote the following function:

```python
def numeric_check(num):
    print "Is an int:", isinstance(num, int)
    print "Is a float:", isinstance(num, float)
    print "Is a complex:", isinstance(num, complex)
    print "Is a numbers.Number:", isinstance(num, numbers.Number)
    print "Is an numbers.Integer:", isinstance(num, numbers.Integral)
    print "Is a numbers.Real:", isinstance(num, numbers.Real)
    print "Is a numbers.Complex:", isinstance(num, numbers.Complex)
    print "Is a numpy.integer:", isinstance(num, numpy.integer)
    print "Is a numpy.floating:", isinstance(num, numpy.floating)
    print "Is a numpy.complex:", isinstance(num, numpy.complex)
```

And ran the following loop:

```python
for dtype in [int, float, complex,
              numpy.int16, numpy.int32, numpy.int64,
              numpy.uint16, numpy.uint32, numpy.uint64,
              numpy.float16, numpy.float32, numpy.float64, numpy.complex64]:
    num = dtype()
    print dtype
    numeric_check(num)
```

I'll spare you the full output but a few excerpts:

```
    type 'int'
    Is an int: True
    Is a float: False
    Is a complex: False
    Is a numbers.Number: True
    Is an numbers.Integer: True
    Is a numbers.Real: True
    Is a numbers.Complex: True
    Is a numpy.integer: False
    Is a numpy.floating: False
    Is a numpy.complex: False
```

So as can be expected from the above, `int` is an instance of any type in the `numbers` module. On my machine the default `numpy` integer is 64bit, let's take a look:

```
    type 'numpy.int64'
    Is an int: True
    Is a float: False
    Is a complex: False
    Is a numbers.Number: True
    Is an numbers.Integer: True
    Is a numbers.Real: True
    Is a numbers.Complex: True
    Is a numpy.integer: True
    Is a numpy.floating: False
    Is a numpy.complex: False
```

It matches the same types as `int` and additionally passes as a `numpy.integer`. Let's check a `numpy.int16`:

```
    type 'numpy.int16'
    Is an int: False
    Is a float: False
    Is a complex: False
    Is a numbers.Number: False
    Is an numbers.Integer: False
    Is a numbers.Real: False
    Is a numbers.Complex: False
    Is a numpy.integer: True
    Is a numpy.floating: False
    Is a numpy.complex: False
```

Ouch, it only passes as a `numpy.integer`. So my questions:

1. Is this Sparta?
2. Is the type separation of the `numpy` part a design choice?
3. Duck typing aside, if I wanted to check numeric types am I best off ignoring the `numbers` module and instead doing the following?

Type checks:

```python
isinstance(num, (int, numpy.integer)
isinstance(num, (float, numpy.floating)
isinstance(num, (complex, numpy.complex)
```

Answer (score 5):

the classes in numbers are Abstract Base Classes, you can register numpy.int* as Integral:

```
import numpy as np
import numbers
numbers.Integral.register(numpy.integer)
a = np.int16(100)
isinstance(a, numbers.Integral)
```

But the range of numpy.int16 is smaller than int, if you do calculation with numpy.int16, overflow may occurred.

Comment: I didn't know about the register capability that's quite handy. Still the MRO of the `numbers` classes seem odd. From a mathematical point of view I can see that an integer may be a specific rational, real or complex number but from the programming side that MRO seems unhelpful. So in essence, if I wanted to check the type of a number I'd first have to check for complex, then real, then rational and finally integer.